# powerpoint for Mac version 16.51

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want my text holders to hold more than one style format. For example, I want the user to see that they can use bold for the header, and then light for the rest of the text. When I set up the text holder, I can see that there are different 'levels' which suggests this is possible, but even when I edit these levels with different styles, when I create a new slide, the text box still only shows one text style. Hopefully someone can help. I'm not sure if Powerpoint can do this or if I should just give up!

Comment: First, you need to edit the styles in the layout that your slide is based on; go to the slide, then choose View | Slide Master. That will "focus" you on the correct layout. Set the text font/size/styles as you wish; the body text placeholder can have a different style for each indent level. Then when you close Master view and return to your slide, you can indent the line of text holding the text cursor by pressing TAB (or SHIFT+TAB to decrease the indent level). The text will take on the same formatting as the matching indent level on the master layout.

Comment: thank you for the response! I understand about making the changes in the slide master. The issue I'm having is really around HOW to set up the text styles within the text holder, in such a way that I can include more than one text style. I've tried editing the bulleted text that appears in the box (presuming that the separate bullets indicate the possibility of separate text styles?) but when I go to the actual slide, the front end slide, there is only 1 text style available. hope you can still help! thank you

Comment: Each bullet level in the placeholder can have its own formatting. To have text assume the formatting of a given indent level, the text itself has to be indented to that level.